# C# entry point class modifier

Tags: c#, access-modifiers, entry-point, modifier

My question is about entry point in a C# program. I'm using VS 2010 and it automatically generates Program.cs file with program class:

```
class Program 
{
   ...
   static void Main(...)
   ...
}
```

My question is why this class is by default internal? Why is not public? An if there are situations to chose one ore another modifier, how to understand which one I need for this basic class?

P.S. I am a Java programmer actually and now trying to learn C# but some details are missing from books.
Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, this is the default. You can modify with static, public, or private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assembly generated is an EXE.  You wouldn't normally add a reference to an EXE assembly, which means nothing other than classes within the EXE would access Program--which means `internal` perfectly describes how it would be used.  Prior to .NET 2.0 you actually couldn't refernce and EXE, so `Program` being `public` is wrong because it can be accessed as anything other than `internal`.

Comment: Thanks for help, I have something new to think about now... :)

Answer (score 3):

Generally there is no need to use *primary* class (which contains entry-point method definition) outside the *assembly* and that's why it has internal access.

Answer (score 1):

each project can have its own entry point, you can also specify entry points to tell a individual project to execute the other. and IAbstract is right You can modify with static, public, or private